# Most efficient way to add a value to a range of values in a list in Python?

Tags: python, performance

What is the most efficient way to add an integer to part of a list?

Example :

```
input : [1,5,3,7,4,3]

range of list to modify is 2,4

add 3 to range

output : [1,5,6,10,7,3]
```

Explanation :

First get the sublist using indexes 2 and 4.
Then add 3 to the values in that index. then return a list containing the modified range.

I tried using a loop but its not fast enough. Need a faster method.

Comment: Can you share your attempt so we aren't giving you a worse solution?

Comment: What do you mean by not fast enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the list and then use iterator operations, which is faster than looping with an index:

```
l = [1,5,3,7,4,3]
l[2:5] = map((3).__add__, l[2:5])
```

`l` then becomes `[1, 5, 6, 10, 7, 3]`.

Comment: This is twice as slow as just `for i in range(2,4): l[i] += 3`, so no, this is not at all faster

Comment: thanks! I will try that out and mark it as answered if it works!

Answer (score 6):

Adding a number to any number (supposedly sufficiently small as from the given eg.) is constant amount of time. You will **have** to iterate through those many list elements as in the provided range and add a number to them which is of the order of the length of the range. I don't think you can improve upon this task (i.e. which is asked in the question) although you can save some time on the overall program by handling the list as a [generator object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) if you are dealing with very large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in constant time per each value-added, plus linear time (given multiple queries).

So O(queries + n) aka O(n + q). This is faster than O(q * n)!

Of course, this is a cp approach, so not completely similar to your question, but depending on why your asking, it could be a solution to consider.

First, you can convert your list into a map for constant look up and value time.

Now we will use **Prefix-Sum arrays** for sums!

Given a range to add to, instead of adding to each element in the range (which is linear per every query, so n^2), we can instead add the value to the starting element and then subtract the element from the index after the ending value.

Then we do the same thing for all queries, and at the end we create a prefix sum 'array' with our newly modified map. You can use an array too, but it'll be slower.

If you want an example for implementation, I found a nice [GeeksforGeeks explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constant-time-range-add-operation-array/).